# jquery - Limit number of words in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works well:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-max-characters="120">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia ea esse accusantium nobis adipisci dignissimos? Vel esse facilis perferendis ipsa? Voluptatem earum, ratione! Consequuntur et assumenda minus, aut temporibus alias.</div>

<p data-max-characters="210">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia ea esse accusantium nobis adipisci dignissimos? Vel esse facilis perferendis ipsa? Voluptatem earum, ratione! Consequuntur et assumenda minus, aut temporibus alias.</p>
```

**jquery:**

```
$("div, p").each(function() {
   var textMaxChar = $(this).attr('data-max-characters');

   length = $(this).text().length;
   if(length > textMaxChar) {
       $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, textMaxChar) + '...');
   }
});
```

But I want the same with limited words. Can anyone help me with this please?

Thanks.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk2dmnb/

Comment: Have a look at str_word_count

Answer (score 3):

If you could assume that words are any text blocks separated by a space, than something like this would work

`$(this).text().split(' ').length;`

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk2dmnb/7/

Comment: It works. :) Thank you @stackoverfloweth. Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk2dmnb/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
  $("div, p").each(function(index, currentText) {
       var length=$(this).attr("data-max-characters");
       var texts=$(this).text().split(" ",length).join(" ");
       $(this).text(texts);
  });
```

follow this link https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk2dmnb/8/

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk2dmnb/4/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sanyami Vaidya, but how do I make it work with my code?

Comment: I need this to work with a multiple elements on the page using data attributes. Thanks.

Comment: It also works. :) Thank you @Sanyami Vaidya. Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnk2dmnb/10/